# Deleting a Parse App Programmatically

Tags: api, parse-platform, automation, continuous-integration

I'm looking for a way to programmatically delete a Parse App. [The REST API seems to only support create and update.](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#apps) Does anyone have an idea for how to do it automatically, so it can be part of a Continuous Integration setup?

*Edit: As mentioned below; the reason for this would be to create and tear down a fresh Parse App for each CI run.*

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain, but I highly doubt there is a way to delete an entire app using the REST API or any mechanism outside of the data browser.

> There is no endpoint for dropping a class or deleting all objects when
>   using the REST API. As you pointed out, the best way of doing this
>   would be through the Data Browser.

[Source: Parse help forum](https://www.parse.com/questions/drop-class-or-delete-all-via-rest-api)

I would highly doubt that there is a way to delete an entire app outside of the data browser, given that Parse won't let you drop a class using other means.

On a related note, why would you need to delete the entire Parse app for continuous integration?

Comment: I would like to create a new Parse Environment for each CI run. It would be nice to be able to clean it up afterwards.. ;)

Comment: There actually is a way to drop a complete class, the Schema API, however, the class has to be empty before you can delete it. https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#schemas